# FOREIGN KEY Connection

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

So I have table customers and table bookings

I want to add a Foreign Key to the script so that
the CustID from customers can make a column in bookings and connect.

```
create table customers(
CustID INT NOT NULL,
CustomerName VARCHAR2(25),
CustomerAddress VARCHAR2(50),
CustomerPhone NUMBER(10),
CONSTRAINT pk_cust PRIMARY KEY (CustID) );
```

and

```
create table bookings(
BookID INT NOT NULL,
HotelName VARCHAR2(10),
RoomType VARCHAR2(20),
RoomNumber NUMBER(3),
CustID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (BookID),
CONSTRAINT fk_CustBook FOREIGN KEY (CustID)
REFERENCES customers(CustID)
StartDate VARCHAR2(25),
EndDate VARCHAR2(25),
Duration VARCHAR2(25));
```

error;

```
StartDate VARCHAR2(25),
*
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: The purpose of this web site is not to provide human syntax checkers for you.  You are missing a comma.

Comment: Please do **not** remove your question once it has been answered. That is totally confusing to people reading it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table bookings(
BookID INT NOT NULL,
HotelName VARCHAR2(10),
RoomType VARCHAR2(20),
RoomNumber NUMBER(3),
CustID INT,
StartDate VARCHAR2(25),
EndDate VARCHAR2(25),
Duration VARCHAR2(25),
PRIMARY KEY (BookID),
CONSTRAINT fk_CustBook FOREIGN KEY (CustID)
REFERENCES customers(CustID));
```

You have to declare the primary key and other constraints after you finish declaring the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table bookings(
BookID INT NOT NULL,
HotelName VARCHAR2(10),
RoomType VARCHAR2(20),
RoomNumber NUMBER(3),
CustID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (BookID),
CONSTRAINT fk_CustBook FOREIGN KEY (CustID)
REFERENCES customers1 (CustID),
StartDate VARCHAR2(25),
EndDate VARCHAR2(25),
Duration VARCHAR2(25));
```

see it carefully -- you Have to add comma after this  CONSTRAINT fk_CustBook FOREIGN KEY (CustID)
REFERENCES customers1 (CustID),